# UITabelViewCell contentView keeps resizing

Tags: ios, uitableview

Please have a look at the following pictures in which I created a UITableView with blank spaces between the cells. I created the blank spaces by setting the TableView row height in Storyboard to a different size then the

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

returns. In the code from the cell itself, I've set the contentView autoresizing to:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews{

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
}
```

It all works perfectly as can be seen here:

[image]

However, if you swipe over the cell, the following is the result:

[image]

And the blank space doesn't come back!How to get this right? Thanks!

[image: Rudolf]

Comment: so have you done spacing using custome UITableCellView

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did.

Comment: I do not found any difference in image 1 and 3